# Is there a way to write exponentials in a button in html5?

Tags: html, css

We can use the  tag(superscript tag) to represent something like a^b and e^x in html5. But while using the  tag to make a button, we normally use the 'value' attribute to represent what's gonna be on the button something like this:

```html
<input type="button"class="cutedog" value ="x cube">
```

But we can't really use the sup tag inside the " " because it just prints out the exact thing out something like this: "e(sup)x(/sup)" (I have deliberately put () instead of < and > because stackoverflow does't support this :( )

Anyway can you tell me that how can we put e^x inside "" or is there any way to do this?? Plz help me :))

Comment: Use a `<button>` tag instead

Comment: If you need number exponents, you can use some Unicode characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button>x<sup>3</sup></button>
```